# Angular 2 - Unit test error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular2-routing, karma-jasmine

So, I'm getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` for all the test cases in my module. In my component I'm injecting "ActivatedRoute" and "Router" and in my `ngOnInit()`, I'm getting some data that I'm passing within the routing-module.
These are the files I have:

**custom-routing.module.ts**

```
const casesRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: CustomComponent,
                resolve: {
                    someData: CustomResolver
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'child',
                        component: ChildComponent
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: ':id/edit',
                component: CaseEditComponent,
                resolve: {
                    theCase: CaseDetailResolver
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(casesRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: [
        CustomResolver
    ]
})
export class CustomRoutingModule { }
```

**custom.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-custom',
    styleUrls: ['./custom.component.css'],
    templateUrl: './custom.component.html',
})
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

    public someData: TheData;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
            this.someData = data.someData;
        });
    }

    public navigateTo(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['child'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    }
}
```

**custom.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('CustomComponent', () => {
    let comp: CustomComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomComponent>;
    let router = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
    }

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                CustomComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute,
                    useValue: {
                        data: Observable.of({
                            someData: { id: 1, lastName: 'Last', firstName: 'First' }
                        })
                    }
                },
                {
                    provide: Router,
                    useValue: router
                }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;

        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('should create component', () => {
        expect(comp).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should initialize the component correctly and expect some data returned from ActivatedRoute', () => {
        comp.ngOnInit();
        expect(comp.someData).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should verify the navigate method from router is called', () => {
        comp.navigateTo();
        expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

At first I thought it could be breaking because of the statement in `ngOnInit()` since it's the only case I'm using the `subscribe` method but even the first test where I check the component is defined, is failing. I even added some `console.info()` calls to review that `this.route.data` in the component has some data and it actually has so I have no idea what could be causing it.